# React TypeError: _this2.props.variations.find is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drupal, redux

Not sure why I'm getting this error. I need to loop through the variations and find the id's containing the varid variables. To me this looks right but it's obviously not. I'm sure everyone here is much smarter than me though haha, I'm still very much a newbie at all this.

This function is supposed to allow me to filter down the state so that I have only the needed data and can display that within the page rather than the state containing all of my drupal products. Perhaps there's a more efficient way to do this also, I'm not sure.

Here's the code:

```
class ProductPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            dropdownOpen: false
        };
    }

    toggle() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            dropdownOpen: !prevState.dropdownOpen
        }));
    }

    render() {
        let style = {
            height: this.props.height - 56,
        };

        let product = this.props.products.items.find(o => o.path[0].alias === this.props.router.match.url);
        console.log(product);
        console.log(this.props.variations);

        let variationList = [];

        if (product && this.props.variations) {
            for (let i = 0; i < product.variations.length; i++) {
                let varid = product.variations[i].variation_id;
                let variation = this.props.variations.find(o => o.path[0].alias === varid);
                variationList.push(variation);
            }
        }

        let body = product && product.body.length ? product.body[0].value : null;

        return (
            <div className="App" id="default">
                <div className='MenuBar'>
                    <MenuBar/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div style={style} className="ProductPage row no-gutters">
                        <div className="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
                            <LeftMenuBar/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="outer col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                            <div>
                                <div id="ProductPlacement">
                                  <img src={WomensWear} alt=""/>
                                    <div id="alternate-pics">
                                        <div id="alt-pic">
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="alt-pic">
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="alt-pic">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-xs-5 col-md-5">
                            <div id="ImagePlacement">
                                <div className="ProductTitle">
                                    <h1>First Product</h1>
                                </div>
                                <hr/>
                                <div className="ProductDescription">
                                    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: body}} />
                                </div>
                                <div id="options">
                                    <div id="color">
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="color2">
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="color3">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="options">
                                    <div>
                                        <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle}>
                                            <DropdownToggle caret id="size-dropdown">
                                                Size
                                            </DropdownToggle>
                                            <DropdownMenu>
                                                <DropdownItem>1</DropdownItem>
                                                <DropdownItem>3</DropdownItem>
                                                <DropdownItem>5</DropdownItem>
                                            </DropdownMenu>
                                        </Dropdown>
                                        <div className="AddToCart">
                                            <button className="AddToCart">Add To Cart</button>
                                            <button className="Price">$34.99</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

    export default ProductPage;
```

Comment: what's the result of `console.log(this.props.variations);`

Comment: It's hard to tell but maybe you're passing to `props` something that's not a list, `null` or `undefined` to `variations`

Comment: The result of console.log(this.props.variations); gets me all the variations of all 3 of my products. So basically I get an array of 9 items, which is what I was hoping for. But now that I'm selecting a specific product, I would like to filter down that state to only the variations for the selected product.

Comment: Most likely it is not an array. Prove that by logging out - `console.log(this.props.variations instanceof Array)`

Comment: it says array[9], expand that and you see all of the variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also ran into this issue and through trial and error discovered it was because of copy+paste. Check your reducer(s) to make sure you aren't setting a default of an object `{}` or other type, instead of an array `[]`.

In my case I had (this is ES6 syntax by the way):

```
const someReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'reducer type':
            // get the data etc.
            return [];
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

When I should have had:

```
const someReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'reducer type':
            // get the data etc.
            return [];
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Notice the first line where I'm setting the default. This is used while the api calls are pending, so if it *just happens* to reach the code where `.find()` is being used then you'll get the error.

This is extremely easy to miss because data is retrieved so fast that you can't easily see when the data is the wrong type. Just make sure your default, however you're setting it, is the correct type! Hope that helps someone!